# Herbal Plant identification

Tags: identification, herbs

This plant is growing in what is supposed to be a herb garden. Can someone help me identify it?

- Southeaster PA, USA
- End of April
  [image]

**Update: Beginning of June**[image]
[image]

Comment: Carrot, parsley, poison hemlock, wild carrot and fool's parsley and and.

Comment: Keep an eye on this stuff.  Someone might be able to decipher a much closer ID.  Don't think this is regular edible carrot.  The hairy stem is important.  There are many members of this family that are very poisonous.  I'd allow this to get larger to be able to identify more accurately.   I lived in the middle of suburbia and raised a self planted dude like this, poison hemlock.  I'd worry about those railroad ties...and the chemicals leached into your edible plant beds. Allow one to grow for fun and send a picture when more mature.  Perhaps a seed head but do not allow to go to seed...

Comment: @stormy: maybe it is an other family. I'll not exclude Composite/Asteraceae family.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  This is always so much fun...to try to ID stuff by pictures and a few sentences.

Comment: Definitely Apiaceae family. Did you get a pic of the flower then?

Comment: @J.Musser No, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like chervil. If you want to know definitely,I suggest downloading PLANTNET to your phone, and it's free! It's a go to for me, and it's extremely accurate.

Comment: Hi Kristen, welcome.  We prefer the answers to be standalone.  Is there any chance you can post a photo from there or elsewhere to show that the identification is correct ?